# Scrolling a React app embedded in an iframe using iframe-resizer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, iframe-resizer

I have a React app embedded in an iframe using iframe-resizer:

```
<iframe id="my-frame" src="http://example.com/my-react-app" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<script>iFrameResize({}, 'my-frame')</script>
```

This is working well in general. However when the embedded React app switches from a tall page to a short page, it is possible for the React app to go out of sight completely. I have to manually scroll to the top of the iframe to see the app again. Is there a way to do this automatically? I saw the `scrollTo` API in the iframe-resizer docs, but it's not clear to me how to use it. Do I have to change my React app or the page that embeds it? How? If possible, I would prefer not to change the React app at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are doing well.

Shouldn't the iFrame resize itself to a smaller height when embedded app moves to a smaller page? If that happens, scrollToTop will not be needed in this case.

Provided the embedded app is using iframeResizer.contentWindow.js

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Pranav! You are right that the iFrame resizes itself, however the wrapper page's scrollbar does not change it's position, so it appears as if the iframe has vanished. I have to scroll up to bring the iframe back into view. And yes, the embedded react app does use iframeResizer.contentWindow.js. All that is working fine. I can see the iframe-resizer logs etc.

Comment: Hi Naresh, 
May be resizedCallback will work. It gives iFrame object on which we can call scrollIntoView.

Comment: Thanks, Pranav. `resizedCallback` did the trick. In this callback I simply scroll the element into the view: `resizedCallback: function(messageData) { var element = document.getElementById(messageData.iframe.id); element.scrollIntoView(); }`. Hope this helps others who are having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have now written a React interface to iframe-resizer, which might help with things like this I the future.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer-react

Comment: Thanks for that David. Will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. I am showing a (slides-section of a) react-app through an iframe, which is placed inside a wordpress site. All the resizing worked just fine, but the iframe would be placed out of screen-view when the react page resized after the first interaction within it.

Using [resizeObserver()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) solved the issue for me.

I added some code to the iframe.js file in my wordpress theme, resulting into this:

```
iFrameResize({
    log                     : false, // Enable console logging
  
});

//

let myIframeReady = false
let iframeHeightChanges = 0

document.getElementById('my-iframe').onload = function() {
    myIframeReady = true
}

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  if (!myIframeReady ) {
   return false 
  }
  
  if (iframeHeightChanges === 1) {
    document.getElementById('my-iframe').scrollIntoView()
  }
  
  iframeHeightChanges += 1
})

resizeObserver.observe(document.body)
```

I hope it helps anyone.